# Why doesn't this script work?

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, bash-scripting

I've been using this bash script:

`for i in $(ls); do mv $i a$i; done`

to prepend all filenames in a folder with the letter a. I'm afraid that at some point I'll accidentally use this script in the wrong directory and prepend a ton of filenames that I don't want prepended. So I decided to explicitly cite the path to the file. So now my script looks like this:

`for i in $(ls /cygdrive/c/Users/path/to/Images); do mv /cygdrive/c/Users/path/to/Images/$i /cygdrive/c/Users/path/to/Images/a$i; done`

It does prepend the filename with the letter a, but it also appends the filename with this  symbol.

Any ideas why it would do that?

If it helps any, I'm using cygwin on a Windows 7 box.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is the path always going to be /cygdrive/c/Users/path/to/Images ?    If so, is the real prefix you'll be using just the letter 'a'?  Is this something you will run multiple times or just a one-off?  Judging by your initial statements, you'll run it frequently.

Comment: Yes, that will always be the path. And yes, the real prefix will be the letter 'a'. I will be running this multiple times a day, so yes, very frequently.

Comment: See comments below (in about 5 mins)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never parse the output of 'ls'.  Do this instead:

`for i in *; do mv "$i" "a${i}"; done`

The reason is that file names can have characters like \r or \n in them and parsing 'ls' will NOT find them.

Update:  Useful information at this link:
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

With the above added information from the OP, use this:

```
for i in /cygdrive/c/Users/path/to/Images/*; do mv "$i" "${i%/*}/a${i##*/}"; done
```

THIS WILL DO ONE RELATIVELY BAD THING...  it will rename ALL files, every time you run it.  This means file 'foo' will be 'afoo'.  When you run it again, it will be 'aafoo' then 'aaafoo', etc.  You can program around this by avoiding any files that start with 'a' but that will avoid ALL files starting with 'a' even if they have not yet been renamed in the script.

Comment: I guess I didn't need to store the path in a variable...

Comment: I think this will work perfect. I'm making a more or less dumb system in which I copy all the files I need into the Images folder, run the script, and copy them back to whatever folder they originally came from. One question though, I don't fully understand why "${i%/*}/a${i##*/}" is needed instead of just a$i. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Understood.  Make sure you test it!  The logic looks good in my head, but I haven't personally tested it out.  For your information, read this link:  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073  It describes parameter expansion, which is seen in my script above like this:  "${i%/*}"  As an example, that particular piece will strip off anything after the very last / which in this case leaves just the path and not the filename.  We add the filename after that with "${i##*/}"

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again. I will test this out first.

Answer (score 1):

test for correct directory, or move to correct directory (or both):

from [here](https://www.redhat.com/mirrors/LDP/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html)

```
E_WRONG_DIRECTORY=73

TargetDirectory=/cygdrive/c/Users/path/to/Images

cd $TargetDirectory
echo "Changing names in $TargetDirectory."

if [ "$PWD" != "$TargetDirectory" ]
then    # Keep from wiping out wrong directory by accident.
  echo "Wrong directory!"
  echo "In $PWD, rather than $TargetDirectory!"
  echo "Bailing out!"
  exit $E_WRONG_DIRECTORY
fi
```

Comment: Since other users in my office would like to use my script, this is what I would like to eventually have. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score -2):

Please declare `ls /cygdrive/c/Users/path/to/Images` as a variable.
Please use variable as `${i}` instead of `$i`.
also Use, `" "` for path's .

Comment: Could you explain why that would change anything?

Comment: Please find my updated answer :-)

Comment: Your post clarifies things about bash scripting, not in the functionality of the original script.

Comment: Your post also recommends parsing the output of 'ls' to a variable which is guaranteed not only to not benefit, but possibly keep the same issues that could be presenting itself already.